# MISRAC2012-Rule-18.1_d Problem with Ethernet MAC

Tags: c, static-analysis, misra

I have a clasic ethernet MAC address code in my source code:

```
  netif->hwaddr[0] =  heth.Init.MACAddr[0];
  netif->hwaddr[1] =  heth.Init.MACAddr[1];
  netif->hwaddr[2] =  heth.Init.MACAddr[2];
  netif->hwaddr[3] =  heth.Init.MACAddr[3];
  netif->hwaddr[4] =  heth.Init.MACAddr[4];
  netif->hwaddr[5] =  heth.Init.MACAddr[5];
```

EDIT:

```
#define NETIF_MAX_HWADDR_LEN 6U

u8_t hwaddr[NETIF_MAX_HWADDR_LEN];
```

[image]

When I try to do static analyse in my code I get this error all these lines:
[image]

How can I solve this ?

Comment: We don't have enough information - what if (for instance) `netif->hwaddr` were only 4 bytes large?   Show more code.

Comment: you need to make sure that analyzr knows where pointer points. You need to to rewrite yor data types to archeive it. Misra is a pain in the ..... head

Comment: I added some detail in my topic

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question

Answer (score 1):

The MISRA checker says that you access the array out of bounds, which is obviously also the case:

```
#define NETIF_MAX_HWADDR_LEN 5U

u8_t hwaddr[NETIF_MAX_HWADDR_LEN];

...
netif->hwaddr[5] =  heth.Init.MACAddr[5];
```

Arrays are 0-indexed in the C language. Solve this by not declaring too small arrays.

Comment: Also get rid of home-made integer types and use `stdint.h`. There is absolutely no reason why you shouldn't use that one.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake information I write as a 5U but it is 6U sorry for this.

Comment: @gogogo Ok but the tool says you are accessing index 42 or something...